# Reinforced.Typings is looking for dotnet.exe on MacOS so it can't run

Tags: reinforced-typings

I'm using reinforced.typings version 1.5.9. It was working well with .net46 but does not work in a Core 3.1 project because the target is looking for "dotnet.exe" where on MacOS, it should be "dotnet". By looking at the source code, it seems to me that NETCORE was not properly defined when the package was built.

```
        protected override string GenerateFullPathToTool()
        {
            if (IsCore)
            {
#if NETCORE
                return
                    RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ?
                    "dotnet.exe"
                    : "dotnet";
#else
                return "dotnet.exe"; 
#endif
            }
            return Path.Combine(GetProperRtcliPath(), ToolName);
        }
```

Comment: Am I the only one with this problem? The project defines NETCOREAPP but uses  NETCORE everywhere. NETCORE is never defined.