# Reinforced.Typings can't find dotnet.exe on MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, reinforced-typings

I'm working on a dotnet 5 solution on MacOS and Reinforced.Typings is giving me the following compile error. It's trying to run dotnet.exe, which I suspect is the core of the problem since it doesn't exist on MacOS. Any clues on how to fix it?

```
/Users/myuser/.nuget/packages/reinforced.typings/1.6.1/build/Reinforced.Typings.targets(3,3): Error MSB6003: The specified task executable "" could not be run. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): ApplicationName='dotnet.exe', CommandLine=' "/Users/myuser/.nuget/packages/reinforced.typings/1.6.1/tools/net5.0/rtcli.dll" profile "/var/folders/q3/zth_hlj12ts4w6zc9m42_ctr0000gn/T/tmp316575ae.tmp"', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x0029f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/System.Diagnostics/Process.cs:778 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x0003a] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs:2006 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool (System.String pathToTool, System.String responseFileCommands, System.String commandLineCommands) [0x000c9] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono-pullrequest/pr/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Utilities/ToolTask.cs:711 
  at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute () [0x00433] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono-pullrequest/pr/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Utilities/ToolTask.cs:1519  (MSB6003) (MyProject.Core)
```

My configuration class looks like this:

```
namespace MyProject.Core
{
    public static class ReinforcedTypingsConfiguration
    {
        public static void Configure(ConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Global(x => x.ExportPureTypings()
                                 .CamelCaseForProperties()
                                 .AutoOptionalProperties(true));

            builder.ExportAsInterfaces(TypesToExport);
        }

        private static List<Type> TypesToExport = new()
        {
            typeof(ProductDto)
        };
    }
}
```

My Reinforced.Typings.settings.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RtForceTargetFramework>net5.0</RtForceTargetFramework>
    <RtTargetFile>$(ProjectDir)/contracts.d.ts</RtTargetFile>
    <RtConfigurationMethod>MyProject.Core.ReinforcedTypingsConfiguration.Configure</RtConfigurationMethod>
    <RtDivideTypesAmongFiles>false</RtDivideTypesAmongFiles>
    <RtBypassTypeScriptCompilation>false</RtBypassTypeScriptCompilation>
    <RtDisable>false</RtDisable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Maybe [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693683/ive-installed-dot-net-core-on-mac-but-didnt-find-dotnet-command) can help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the source code of Reinforced.Typings and it internally calls `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)` to determine whether `"dotnet.exe"` or `"dotnet"` will be used.

Try to create a simple console app and check what `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)` returns.

Source code: [RtCli.cs](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/blob/a036544fead3874f008211078f845a88cad5479d/Reinforced.Typings.Integrate/RtCli.cs#L115)

Comment: That's returning `True` for `OSPlatform.OSX` and `False` for `OsPlatform.Windows`, as expected. The if you're referring to is wrapped in a `#if NETCORE` preprocessor directive which I guess is making the code default to dotnet.exe.
Interestingly, the exact same code compiles and works fine with Rider, but not with Visual Studio Community edition for mac, so I guess they're passing in different params somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Reinforced.Typings works as expected from the command line by running `dotnet build *.sln`. It also works from Rider, which wraps the same build command.

Building from Visual Studio for Mac is a different story. It seems to be running an awful lot of stuff on build, but not `dotnet build`. Not entirely sure what command Visual Studio for Mac is running, but it looks like some sort of Target/Task related flow that somehow sets `OsPlatform` to `OsPlatform.Windows` even though it is clearly incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked the same question 10 months ago and still no answer. My guess is that NETCORE was not defined at the time of building the nuget package.

[Reinforced.Typings is looking for dotnet.exe on MacOS so it can't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66553910/reinforced-typings-is-looking-for-dotnet-exe-on-macos-so-it-cant-run)